# Conflict in using the Ipaddress instead of localhost

Tags: cakephp

I am doing my application and running it through by like
http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/controllername/action
eg..
http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/view/1/5/Invitee
results the correct page. which is generated bby using the datas in my Database.
But if i tried to use like
http://myipaddress/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/view/1/5/Invitee

only some parts are retrieved from my database.WHy so ?? Please suggest me..
My application is done using Cakephp , Mysql

Comment: Why does "index.php" appear in your application URLs? Cake uses the domain/controller/action/params URL model; you should have index.php in there anywhere.

Comment: Since i am not having the .htaccess file i am using index.php in my URL else its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should user server IP with port numbers

```
http://ip-address:port/FormBuilder/index.php/controllername/action
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to make this development environment available over the internet? In which case you need to check which port you are using, i.e. 88 or 8888 and you need to check your router / firewall and ensure the port is open and forwarded correctly.